# Cannot cin.ignore till EOF?

Tags: c++, delimiter, cin, flush

I wanted to ignore all characters in `cin` to flush `cin` in this answer: [How to get rid of bad input one word at a time instead of one line at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631534/how-to-get-rid-of-bad-input-one-word-at-a-time-instead-of-one-line-at-a-time/28631871#28631871)

But I found that the program seemed to hang awaiting input if I wrote:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

It propperly flushed `cin` if I used the `'\n'` delimiter:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

My question is, why can't I just ignore till EOF? Why do I have to provide the delimiter?

Comment: You *can* ignore till EOF. You *did* ignore till EOF. You just didn't realize what that actually means. ;-)

Comment: Did you make it reach the end of `cin`, either by redirecting from a file or other finite source, or hitting CTRL-D or whatever it is on your platform? Otherwise, it will wait for input to ignore forever.

Comment: So your desire is to discard all characters that have been currently entered, then start reading normally? That's a good question.

Comment: @MarkRansom Right. It seems the answer was more clear than I thought it was, I just didn't understand `ignore`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ignore` function name is a little bit misleading.  What it actually does it **read** and **discard** input until the terminator is found.  And that's a blocking read.

In your case, whatever input stream you are using with `cin` (by default it is `stdin`) never delivers an end-of-file condition, so `ignore`'s read/discard loop blocks forever.

Comment: Unless  a pipeline is involved - than the writing end is emitting an EOF when closing. Another exemption is a user input in a terminal supporting EOF (Linux: ctrl-D)

Comment: On Windows you can mark EOF on the console with Ctrl-Z+Enter, and on *nix you do it with Ctrl-D. So it's not impossible to break out, just unlikely if you don't know the trick.

Comment: @Dieter, Mark: Right, I didn't say that the input stream is incapable of delivering an EOF, just that in his case it is not doing so.