# How to restart loop if an alphabet is given as input by user in C++

Tags: c++, loops, user-input, invalid-characters, defensive-programming

I have written a code about guessing a secret number, but I have a problem when an alphabetic character is given as an input instead of an integer. It halts the program. What how can I resist this problem.

```
srand(time(0));
int a,secret;
secret=rand() % 10 +3;
do{
        cout<<"Guess the secret num between 1-10 + 3 : ";
cin>>a;
else if(a>secret)
{
    cout<<"Secret num is smaller!!"<<endl;
}
else if(a<secret) {
    cout<<"Secret num is greater !!"<<endl;
}

}
while(a!=secret)
cout<<"   "<<endl;
cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"Congratulations!!!! This is the secret num...."<<secret<<endl;
```

Comment: code does not compile. Show us actual code. (where is first if?)

Comment: You have to use `cin.clear()` to reset the fail state if the input stream after an invalid input was given.

Comment: Check out the `continue` keyword

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `clear` is good but `ignore` is also required here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to, but if you still want to solve the problem, you can stream the line and get the line in number only.

[Answered by Jesse Good here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828937/how-to-make-cin-take-only-numbers):

> I would use `std::getline` and `std::string` to read the whole line
>   and then only break out of the loop when you can convert the entire
>   line to a double.
>
> ```
> #include <string>
> #include <sstream>
>
> int main()
> {
>   std::string line;
>   double d;
>   while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
>   {
>       std::stringstream ss(line);
>       if (ss >> d)
>       {
>           if (ss.eof())
>           {   // Success
>               break;
>           }
>       }
>       std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
>   }
>   std::cout << "Finally: " << d << std::endl;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, because 0 is outside the allowable range this is really simple:

1. Initialize `a` to 0 and if `a` is 0 after extracting:
2. [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) `cin`
3. [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) `cin` (Be careful to specify that you want to ignore up to the newline character: [Cannot cin.ignore till EOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633195/cannot-cin-ignore-till-eof))

Your final code should look something like this:

```
cout << "Guess the secret num between 1-10 + 3 : ";
cin >> a;

while (a != secret) {
    if (a == 0) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Please enter a valid number between 1-10 + 3 : ";
    }
    else if (a < secret) {
        cout << "Secret num is smaller!!\nGuess the secret num between 1-10 + 3 : ";
    }
    else if (a < secret) {
        cout << "Secret num is greater !!\nGuess the secret num between 1-10 + 3 : ";
    }
    a = 0;

    cin >> a;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/XYL78z)